# How to determine if error is from JMeter or due to load on server

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

So far I understand that if there is a problem with JMeter, we get error messages. I have not got any errors from JMeter regarding memory.

**Scenario:** 
I am using different virtual machines to perform the load test.  So JMeter is hosted on a VM and server is another VM and I keep on increasing the size of the server. The VM size could range from 1 vcpus, 1 GiB memory to 20 vcpus, 80 GiB memory.

**Issue:**
I run the same test on all VM (small to big) and I am having error on the same number of users on all machines.  I have used to different programming language to develop the same app to rule out the possibility that the error was not in the app itself.  However, I got the same result (max users before error as same with both app)

**Question:**
Recently, I have tried to increase the number of users until I started getting errors. I have followed https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter/

I have observed that the threshold for the maximum users on all machines is the same irrespective of the size of the VM, i.e 8000 users

I have a suspicion that the errors could also be due to JMeter as in the post, it`s said that 10000 users is the limit.  Can someone help me to identify where the error is coming from, atleast, I can rule out the possibility that it is not from JMeter?

I will really appreciate if someone could also guide.
Thanks is advance!

**Config files:**

My Config files (which I have modified) are as follows:
Jmeter.Propperties

```html
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HTTP Cache Manager configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Space or comma separated list of methods that can be cached
#cacheable_methods=GET
# N.B. This property is currently a temporary solution for Bug 56162

# Since 2.12, JMeter does not create anymore a Sample Result with 204 response
# code for a resource found in cache which is inline with what browser do.
#cache_manager.cached_resource_mode=RETURN_NO_SAMPLE

# You can choose between 3 modes:
# RETURN_NO_SAMPLE (default)
# RETURN_200_CACHE
# RETURN_CUSTOM_STATUS

# Those mode have the following behaviours:
# RETURN_NO_SAMPLE:
# this mode returns no Sample Result, it has no additional configuration

# RETURN_200_CACHE:
# this mode will return Sample Result with response code to 200 and
# response message to "(ex cache)", you can modify response message by setting
# RETURN_200_CACHE.message=(ex cache)

# RETURN_CUSTOM_STATUS:
# This mode lets you select what response code and message you want to return,
# if you use this mode you need to set those properties
# RETURN_CUSTOM_STATUS.code=
# RETURN_CUSTOM_STATUS.message=
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# true when field should be saved; false otherwise

# assertion_results_failure_message only affects CSV output
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
#
# legitimate values: none, first, all
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none
#
#jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
# response_data is not currently supported for CSV output
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
# Save ResponseData for failed samples
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
# Only available with HttpClient4
#jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
# Only available with HttpClient4
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=true
```

setenv.sh

```html
rem This is the content of bin\setenv.bat,
rem it will be called by bin\jmeter.bat

set JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dpropname=value"
# This is the file bin/setenv.sh,
# it will be sourced in by bin/jmeter

# Use a bigger heap, but a smaller metaspace, than the default
export HEAP="-Xms1G -Xmx2G -XMaxMetaspaceSize=192m"

# Try to guess the locale from the OS. The space as value is on purpose!
export JMETER_LANGUAGE=" "
```

Jmeter.bat

```html
@echo off

rem   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
rem   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
rem   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
rem   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
rem   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
rem   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem 
rem       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem 
rem   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem   limitations under the License.

rem   =====================================================
rem   Environment variables that can be defined externally:
rem
rem   Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script
rem   setenv.bat in JMETER_HOME/bin to keep your customizations separate.
rem
rem   DDRAW       - (Optional) JVM options to influence usage of direct draw,
rem                 e.g. '-Dsun.java2d.ddscale=true'
rem
rem   JMETER_BIN  - JMeter bin directory (must end in \)
rem
rem   JMETER_COMPLETE_ARGS - if set indicates that JVM_ARGS is to be used exclusively instead
rem                 of adding other options like HEAP or GC_ALGO
rem
rem   JMETER_HOME - installation directory. Will be guessed from location of jmeter.bat
rem
rem   JM_LAUNCH   - java.exe (default) or javaw.exe
rem
rem   JM_START    - set this to 'start ""' to launch JMeter in a separate window
rem                 this is used by the jmeterw.cmd script.
rem
rem   JVM_ARGS    - (Optional) Java options used when starting JMeter, e.g. -Dprop=val
rem                 Defaults to '-Duser.language="en" -Duser.region="EN"'
rem
rem   GC_ALGO     - (Optional) JVM garbage collector options 
rem                 Defaults to '-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20'
rem
rem   HEAP        - (Optional) JVM memory settings used when starting JMeter
rem                 Defaults to '-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m'
rem
rem   =====================================================

setlocal

rem Guess JMETER_HOME if not defined
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
if not "%JMETER_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set "JMETER_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"
if exist "%JMETER_HOME%\bin\jmeter.bat" goto okHome
cd ..
set "JMETER_HOME=%cd%"
cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"
if exist "%JMETER_HOME%\bin\jmeter.bat" goto okHome
set "JMETER_HOME=%~dp0\.."
:gotHome

if exist "%JMETER_HOME%\bin\jmeter.bat" goto okHome
echo The JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
goto end
:okHome

rem Get standard environment variables
if exist "%JMETER_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat" call "%JMETER_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat"

if not defined JMETER_LANGUAGE (
    rem Set language
    rem Default to en_EN
    set JMETER_LANGUAGE=-Duser.language="en" -Duser.region="EN"
)

rem Minimal version to run JMeter
set MINIMAL_VERSION=1.8.0


rem --add-opens if JAVA 9
set JAVA9_OPTS=


for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
    rem @echo Debug Output: %%g
    set JAVAVER=%%g
)
if not defined JAVAVER (
    @echo Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
    set ERRORLEVEL=2
    goto pause
)



rem Check if version is from OpenJDK or Oracle Hotspot JVM prior to 9 containing 1.${version}.x
rem JAVAVER will be equal to "9.0.4" (quotes are part of the value) for Oracle Java 9
rem JAVAVER will be equal to "1.8.0_161" (quotes are part of the value) for Oracle Java 8
rem so we extract 2 chars starting from index 1
IF "%JAVAVER:~1,2%"=="1." (
    set JAVAVER=%JAVAVER:"=%
    for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%v in ("%JAVAVER%") do (
        set current_minor=%%w
)
) else (
    rem Java 9 at least
    set current_minor=9
    set JAVA9_OPTS=--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED
)


for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%v in ("%MINIMAL_VERSION%") do (
    set minimal_minor=%%w
)

if not defined current_minor (
    @echo Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
    set ERRORLEVEL=2
    goto pause
)
rem @echo Debug: CURRENT=%current_minor% - MINIMAL=%minimal_minor%
if %current_minor% LSS %minimal_minor% (
    @echo Error: Java version -- %JAVAVER% -- is too low to run JMeter. Needs a Java version greater than or equal to %MINIMAL_VERSION%
    set ERRORLEVEL=3
    goto pause
)

if not defined JM_LAUNCH (
    set JM_LAUNCH=java.exe
)

if exist jmeter.bat goto winNT1
if not defined JMETER_BIN (
    set JMETER_BIN=%~dp0
)

:winNT1
rem On NT/2K grab all arguments at once
set JMETER_CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*

rem The following link describes the -XX options:
rem http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

    if not defined HEAP (
    rem See the unix startup file for the rationale of the following parameters,
    rem including some tuning recommendations
    set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=8000m 

)
set JVM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx8000m 
rem Uncomment this to generate GC verbose file with Java prior to 9 
rem set VERBOSE_GC=-verbose:gc -Xloggc:gc_jmeter_%%p.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy

rem Uncomment this to generate GC verbose file with Java 9 and above
rem set VERBOSE_GC=-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,gc+heap=debug:file=gc_jmeter_%%p.log
rem You may want to add those settings
rem -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem
if not defined GC_ALGO (
    set GC_ALGO=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20
)

set SYSTEM_PROPS=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom

rem Always dump on OOM (does not cost anything unless triggered)
set DUMP=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

rem Uncomment this if you run JMeter in DOCKER (need Java SE 8u131 or JDK 9)
rem see https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-se-support-for-docker-cpu-and-memory-limits
rem set RUN_IN_DOCKER=-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap

rem Additional settings that might help improve GUI performance on some platforms
rem See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/perf-graphics-135933.html

if not defined DDRAW (
    set DDRAW=
    rem  Setting this flag to true turns off DirectDraw usage, which sometimes helps to get rid of a lot of rendering problems on Win32.
    rem set DDRAW=%DDRAW% -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true

    rem  Setting this flag to false turns off DirectDraw offscreen surfaces acceleration by forcing all createVolatileImage calls to become createImage calls, and disables hidden acceleration performed on surfaces created with createImage .
    rem set DDRAW=%DDRAW% -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false

    rem Setting this flag to true enables hardware-accelerated scaling.
    rem set DDRAW=%DDRAW% -Dsun.java2d.ddscale=true
)

rem Collect the settings defined above
if not defined JMETER_COMPLETE_ARGS (
    set ARGS=%JAVA9_OPTS% %DUMP% %HEAP% %VERBOSE_GC% %GC_ALGO% %DDRAW% %SYSTEM_PROPS% %JMETER_LANGUAGE% %RUN_IN_DOCKER%
) else (
    set ARGS=
)

if "%JM_START%" == "start" (
    set JM_START=start "Apache_JMeter"
)

%JM_START% "%JM_LAUNCH%" %ARGS% %JVM_ARGS% -jar "%JMETER_BIN%ApacheJMeter.jar" %JMETER_CMD_LINE_ARGS%

rem If the errorlevel is not zero, then display it and pause

if NOT errorlevel 0 goto pause
if errorlevel 1 goto pause

goto end

:pause
echo errorlevel=%ERRORLEVEL%
pause

:end
```

**Test:**

I carried test with as follow on all machines.

No of users: 8000

No of loops: 10

Ramp-up period : 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The number of virtual users you can simulate with JMeter is much more than 10 000, the theoretical upper limit is [2,147,483,647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647) just make sure to:

1. Follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Monitor the usage of CPU, RAM, Network and Disk IO, Java Heap and GC activity, it can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
3. Start your test with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load until you resources usage starts exceeding i.e. 80% of total available CPU, RAM, etc. At this point check how many virtual users are online using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener - **this is how many users you can simulate for particular this test from particular this machine**. If it is 8000 or more - you're good to go, if it's less - you will have to go for [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)